# How to start a class which extends broadcast receiver?

Tags: android

I am new in android app development, i am making an answering machine app, and need help..

1. How to start a class which extends broadcastreceiver when i am in my launcher class ?
2. Which method to use for automatically picking up the call ?

Kindly help

Comment: what to do with broadcastreceiver?

Answer (score 0):

1. Creating broadcast reciever

   ```
   public class Yourclass extends BroadcastReceiver {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         Toast.makeText(context, "Intent Detected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }

   }
   ```

2.Registering broadcast reciever

You can register this either in manifest or by writing `Context.registerReceiver() method.`

Here is the example for manifest

```
<application
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

   <receiver android:name="MyReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">
      </action>
      </intent-filter>
   </receiver>

</application>
```

1. When your application is in defined state calls onRecieve() method  to perform your required action.